# Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main when run hbase shell

Tags: hbase

I am new in hbase. I installed hbase-0.98.5-hadoop2 single node in my Ubuntu 12.04.
I finished hbase installation and tried to run **hbase shell** command in my terminal.

```
indi60@arrasyid:/hack/hbase-0.98.5-hadoop2$ ./bin/hbase shell
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main
```

I tried googling this error, but I did not find any solution about it. Please tell me what should I do for this error. Should I add some export configuration or install some stuff. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for this, I am getting same error!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I solved by set HBASE_HOME in ~/.bashrc. Make sure that **jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar** file found in your $HBASE_HOME/lib.